# Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere 6 Trigger - Trying to detect if im INSERTING or UPDATING

Tags: sql, triggers, sybase-asa

In v10 of the Sybase Adaptive Server Anywhere inside a trigger i can check what event executed the trigged by using:

```
IF UPDATING THEN
-- Do Stuff
END IF;

IF INSERTING THEN
-- Do Stuff
END IF;
```

However in v6 this is not recognised. Any idea how i can do the same or will i just need to create two separate triggers. One for updating and one for inserting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, version 6 did not support this functionality. You will have to write separate triggers for each action. Please note that version 6 is almost fifteen years old; you should consider upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: ok thanks. Yes i know its old but im just working on a project for a customer. I dont control what database they use.